# Error during endpoints discovery doc generation with Groovy annotated @Api class

Tags: maven, groovy, google-cloud-endpoints, google-app-engine

I've an AppEngine (Java) project with cloud endpoints. It has Groovy support through:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.0-01</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.8-01</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Everything seems to work except `endpoints_get_discovery_doc` that gives me this error during `mvn install`:

```
Error: xxx.XxxEndpoint.XxxEndpoint.super$1$finalize: Invalid method name 'XxxEndpoint.super$1$finalize'. The method name must match '\w+(\.\w+)*'
[INFO] Endpoints discovery doc generation done.
```

When I change XxxEndpoint.groovy to a plain XxxEndpoint.java, it generates successfully and the API can be discovered through the API explorer.

Any idea how to fix this or Groovy (I tried with @CompileStatic also) based @Api class endpoints are not (yet?) a supported feature?

UPDATE: I think it is because all methods in an @Api class will be exposed as API methods and Groovy's generated methods are not welcomed in this case. The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#apimethod_method-scoped_annotations) say: "...all public, non static, non bridge methods in a class with an @Api annotation are exposed in the API, whether they have an @ApiMethod annotation or not."

If this is true, then it is possible to exclude methods in an @Api class from being exposed as an @ApiMethod?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've traced down the answer to your own question here. Groovy is working in such a way that it's adding these methods, which aren't enjoyed by the endpoints discovery doc/client lib generation tools. You could try playing around with the order in which the plugins are run so that groovy adds its methods after the discovery doc is generated?

Comment: You should open a feature request on the [public issue tracker for App Engine](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list). I think an annotation to ignore methods in the Api class when generating the discovery doc would be a great feature for just situations like this. I feel a method without the ApiMethod annotation should not be grabbed.